# Sum of two data property of two individuals

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, owlready

hi I am working with ontology on protege 5.5.0
I have a **concept :** 'Country' which have individuals: Italy, Spain, France....
Each of the individual have a data property **cases**
I want to have a new individual Europe which have the same data property (cases) and have the sum of the cases of all the individuals of country.

Is this possible to do! if yes some one gives me any idea

Comment: OWL has no means of `sum` or any math calculation. Try SWRL and hope it works